# Female names associated with healing/caring and peacefulness

Tags: names

I am looking for some extremely *non* threatening *sounding* female English names, that is, names which have connotations, for native speakers, which would be the opposite of killing and maiming -- names that would make you think "This woman is worthless in battle".

I am looking for names which are based on words or word origins associated with peacefulness or healing/caring. Many female names are also words found in the English language, for example Rose and May, but these do not have the meaning I am looking for.

This will be ironic (names for the two most deadly starfighter pilots of one faction).

Comment: Doug and Kevin.

Comment: Erynnis,  Hesperia are the names of butterflies. The first is from vengeance, the other means nightfall.

Comment: Flower names are right in this territory. Rose, Daisy, Hyacinth, etc.

Comment: ... Belladonna?

Comment: ... Sissibelle? refers to princess Sissi and beauty: not a warrior.

Comment: This question reminds me of *Fluffy* from Harry Potter – a non-threatening dog name.

Comment: Suggest 'Harmony' and 'Clementine' (mild and merciful)

Comment: I think the question's on-topic. Names have connotations; a question about "consensus opinion" isn't a question about individual opinion. Almost all grammatical questions rely upon consensus, after all.

Comment: *Freda* would be good, but the people who know it is related to "peace" have been dead for a thousand years. Flower names are best, though girls named Daisy are often good rasslers.

Comment: "Faith" is a good one too.

Answer (score 3):

I think an old lady name could work really well because it carries the additional image of an old feeble granny. Something like Gertrude or Agnes or Eleanor sound like they could be someone's great aunt. Other names that could work: Marie Elizabeth, Tiffany, Fleur.

Comment: Names run in cycles, so great-aunt names become the names of nieces, and lost their great-auntie-ness.

Comment: lost should read lose